# Can we use the structure "as very + adj + as"?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. He is very very brave as a lion.
> 2. He is as very brave as a lion.
> 3. He is as brave as a lion.

Can we use the structure "as very + adj + as"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, number 2 is not correct. "Very" is redundant in 2. 3 and 1 mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Sentences 1 and 2 are both flawed; sentence 3 is correct as written.

Sentence 1:
We don't say "**very [adjective] as**" in this sense.  Instead you might say something like:

> He is very (very) brave, *like* a lion.

In informal conversation you might hear someone omit the first *as* in the comparison and say something like:

> He is brave as a lion.

It's not particularly good English, but it definitely occurs from time to time.  The sentence sounds much better with *as* before the word *brave*.

Sentence 2:
This format doesn't work.  When we're constructing a simile in this way we don't use *very* in the middle of the comparison.  You might be able to force a different adverb into its place, but it's still not going to sound quite right.

Sentence 3:
Again, this is correct as written.